# iOS 10 Ad Information Availability to Devs

Tags: api, ios10, ads, privacy

In iOS 10, Apple added screens under the Settings > Privacy that allow users to see information collected about their activities, such as content they've download from Books, Movies, etc. as well as advertising segments in which they have been included based on their interactions with advertisers etc.
Is that information somehow accessible by developers? If so, which part of the iOS 10 API?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Media Library ("user’s collections of images, audio, and video") is accessible to app developers, with user permission: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/medialibrary

There are similar APIs for each of the data categories in the iOS Privacy Settings, and each category requires explicit user permission before access is allowed.

Apple uses user info to create segments that contain at least 5,000 people, and Apple indicates on its "About Advertising & Privacy" support page that a user's Advertising segments are not directly accessible to app developers:

> Apple does not sell or otherwise transmit any personally identifiable
>   information to third parties.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205223